# Ajaxcontroltoolkit roundedcornersextender is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Following is the sample code.. I cannot find any rounded corners for the table. .. 
I can't fix the error... plz,help

```
            <cc1:roundedcornersextender id="rce" runat="server" targetcontrolid="tbl"
        radius="10" corners="All" />
    <table id="tbl" runat="server" style="border: medium solid #0000FF; width: 41%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Are you using Ajax 1.0 and IE8? Try Viewing in Chrome or firefox, I've had issues with IE8 showing rounded corners.

Comment: I'm using Ajax 2.0 and IE7. I tried in all browser. I can't see the rounded corners??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this sample code its work fine for me in IE7 & IE8

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .myborder
        {
            background-color:Green;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="RoundedPanel" CssClass="myborder" Width="200px" Height="80px">
            <table id="tbl" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                     <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Testing
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
         <cc1:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="RoundedPanel" radius="10" corners="All" >
         </cc1:RoundedCornersExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

please provide height & width values for Panel,

Screen shot of output[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the table in a panel and use the panel as your target.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="Blue">
  <table>....</table>
<asp:Panel>
<cc1:roundedcornersextender id="rce" runat="server" targetcontrolid="Panel1" radius="10" corners="All" />
```